# Sample Multi Process applications in Linux

Tags: multiprocessing

We are working on project in Linux, we need to use some real world multi-process applications to demonstrate its features.

I could not find any multi-process applications in Linux.

Please help me with the name of such applications.

Answer (score 1):

Any shell pipeline:

```
grep whatever myfile | head -100
```

Uses two processes (grep and head) to show you the first hundred lines containing `whatever` in `myfile`.  This sort of thing is all over the place in Linux, or any *nix-like system.  More specifically, it is a key feature to implement the Unix Philosophy, and is central to any shell, like Bash, Korn Shell, Z Shell, Dash, C Shell, etc.

Linux is made of multiprocessing.  If you still aren't convinced, look at `sshd` which accepts incoming logins from other machines by spawning a process for each one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think, I missed an important point.  I am looking for applications with inter process communication via shared memory segments, semaphores or message queues. Not pipes and sockets.